# static variables stores values from 1 class but does not display in 2nd class c# unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

i have 3 classes.

1. static class in which i declared 2 game objects

   ```
   public static Gameobject attacker;
   public static Gameobject defender;
   ```
2. attack combination in which i chose attacker and defender , in this
   scene it gets and display values fine ,

   ```
   staticclass.attacker = gameObject;
   Debug.Log("I am attacker" + staticclass.attacker);
   ```

but it is not displaying values n 3rd class result class , any idea how to do that

3. diceresult

   ```
   Debug.Log(" ATTAKERRRRRRRRRRRR " + staticclass.attacker);
   ```

dice result is in another scene

Comment: Was it changed between 2 calls?

Comment: Do you have multiple declarations of `staticclass`?

Comment: `Game object`? Don't you mean `GameObject`?

Comment: What's the output when you run `Debug.Log(" ATTAKERRRRRRRRRRRR " + staticclass.attacker);`? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen no there is only one static class. but i am calling it in 2 different scripts, in 1st one 1 am getting values and in 2nd i am trying to access them

Comment: @Kirhgoph it displayes  "ATTAKERRRRRRRRRRRR null"

Comment: @tym32167 yes when i call it in another class it is showing null

Comment: Are you sure you're checking this attacker field from the 3rd class after the assignment in the 2nd class and not before? Looks like in the time you check this value it was never assigned before

Comment: You mean it stops working after loading new scene?

Comment: yes @Programmer , diceresult is in another scene.where i want to access them

Answer (score 2):

When you make GameObject, Component or any script/component that derives from the Unity's [Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) `static`, it will **still** be **destroyed/cleaned up** when you load new scene.

If you don't want this to happen that you must call [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) on all those Unity [Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) `static` variables immediately after initializing them.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(attacker);
DontDestroyOnLoad(defender);
```

Comment: Does Unity unload the assembly with those types? Because static fields survives garbage collection of instances of the object.

Comment: I don't know if Unity unloads the assembly with those types. The problem is that people confuse C# `System.Object` with Unity's `Object`. Everything in Unity inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` not `System.Object`. The garbage collection work very differently with Unity's Object. They are destroyed even when made static. Exceptions are the basic primitive types such as int, float...

Comment: i tried but it is still showing null, i made awake function in my all scripts and call it , but its still showing null ,  DontDestroyOnLoad(attacker);
DontDestroyOnLoad(defender);